# Pulse Audio showing not inputs after booting from windows

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio

So I was playing some games on windows, when I was done I booted back into kubuntu 21.10 only to find that pulse audio showed no sound devices(in or out). What could have caused this.

Also I restarted pulseaudio from the command line and here's the output

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 15.0
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 0081e8d687044493bb550f090cba15e9.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 1.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/maximummaxx/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-15.0+dfsg1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 MMXEXT 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'device-volumes' database file '/home/maximummaxx/.config/pulse/0081e8d687044493bb550f090cba15e9-device-volumes.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'stream-volumes' database file '/home/maximummaxx/.config/pulse/0081e8d687044493bb550f090cba15e9-stream-volumes.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'card-database' database file '/home/maximummaxx/.config/pulse/0081e8d687044493bb550f090cba15e9-card-database.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-connect" (index: #5; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 0 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #6; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-policy" (index: #7; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluez5-discover" (index: #9; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-discover" (index: #8; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #10; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-gsettings" (index: #11; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: No previous default sink setting, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: No previous default source setting, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #12; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring mute state for sink auto_null: unmuted
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
I: [null-sink] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #14; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #13; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #16; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 0 "Login Session 1"
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: exit_idle_time: 20 -> 0
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #17; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #18; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-role-cork" (index: #19; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-snap-policy" (index: #20; argument: "").
I: [snapd-glib] module-snap-policy.c: Starting GLib main loop
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #21; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #22; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 1 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=1000 gid=1000 success=1
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink auto_null idle for too long, suspending ...
E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.`
```

Comment: Open terminal and enter... pavucontrol.  This is a gui to help you select the devices.  If nothing at all is displayed, likely you have a corrupted system - in which case you are likely better off to perform a fresh install to 21.10 , than to spend hours or days trying to debug.  A fresh install is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Before going the nuke & pave way suggested above, boot Windows and disable Fast Startup and shutdown. Try booting Kubuntu again and all devices should be available again.